# What is the best alternative power supply for DC water pump?

Tags: dc-motor

I have a 180 watts 12 volts DC  water pump but I don't want to use a battery or solar power to operate it, instead I want to use  a AC to DC converter and I don't know what I should use.

Comment: They have power supplies for HAM radio equipment. You can look for one of those. At least 200 Watts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually off-topic as it is a shopping question. But just search for a 12V switching supply at least 180 watts.

Answer (score 4):

You can buy a switching power supply, however with a pump motor load I would suggest going for a much higher rating than the motor nameplate. Maybe 360-600W without  having more information.

Or rated for at least the motor "L.R.A." multiplied by the voltage (Locked Rotor Amperes), if you can get that number.

Switching supplies have a tendency to go into protection mode when connected to motor loads since the inrush current is much higher than the steady-state current. That stalls the motor and it never starts.

Comment: I currently have a switching supply with 230w and like you said it never starts because it automatically cuts the power when I plug in. Is there a modification that i can do to the supply to make it run?

Comment: @RedDevin  Personally, I would not attempt it.